Image loaded in KMP Desktop is blurry using coil
I'm currently learning KMP with Desktop and Android platform, and this is my first desktop development. And, i run into problem where an image loaded on desktop is in bad quality compared to in android. Both are rendered using same code and same coil library. I tried to raise the size of composable because some folks say it's due to rendering it on small place. But, even on 450dp or 450 pixel (my monitor has 1.0 pixel density), it still not as normal compared to looking the image via my browser or photo viewer.
Here is the code to render the image
AsyncImage(
  model = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
    .data(imageUrl)
    .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
    .build(),
      contentDescription = title,
      contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
      modifier = Modifier
        .width(125.dp)
        .aspectRatio(3 / 4F)
)

Here's the comparison

Updated:
Here's the comparison between the same image, left one is using Image composable with local data, and right one is using Coil with image url since i can't figure out how to make coil load local image

As you can see, the one that using Image composable doesn't have any weird effect on it. Both are 250dp/250px because the image size is 256 pixel wide

try adding image source to resources and see if the issue persists with static image, without coil - depending on the result, you may want to file an issue on coil or compose multiplatform github.

I updated the question, and seems like it is related to the coil itself

Stack Overflow is not a issue tracker, when facing unexpected behavior of a library you should report it to the maintainers, in this case here
